# Powershell toLower Get-FileHash

Tags: powershell, hash, tolower

I have this command

```
    ... | select-object name, fullname, @{Name = "MD5"; Expression = { (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash } }
```

How do I properly toLower the MD5 Hash?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like ..`.Hash.ToLower()` did the trick